# How to run dart code at specific time, even when app is not running flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, alarm

I want to run dart code in background(even when app is killed/not running).
I have check alarm manager but that is restricted to Android i need solution for both.

I have a reminder app, there is a feature if user turn off a reminders then reminder should be activated next day,

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: @Salish kumar have you found solution about it i also want same situation

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run the Dart code by referencing [Executing Dart in the Background with Flutter Plugins and Geofencing](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124).

There are both solutions the Android and the IOS. I think the key point is `callbackDispatcher` to create the entry point for the background isolate.